# Does every channel admit a Stinespring dilation using as ancilla a mixed state?

Tags: density-matrix, linear-algebra

The Stinespring dilation theorem states that any CPTP map $\Lambda$ on a system with Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ can be represented as $$\Lambda[\rho]=tr_\mathcal{A}(U^\dagger (\rho\otimes |\phi\rangle\langle \phi|)U)$$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is an [ancilla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancilla_bit), $|\phi\rangle\in\mathcal{A}$ is an arbitrary pure state, and $U$ is a unitary on the joint system $\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{A}$. Importantly, this works for *any* choice of the state $|\phi\rangle\in\mathcal{A}$ -- that is,  neither does $|\phi\rangle\in\mathcal{A}$ have to depend on $\Lambda$, nor is a specific choice of $|\phi\rangle\in\mathcal{A}$ required.

Would this representation still be valid if, instead of attaching an ancilla in the pure state $|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|$, we instead attached an ancilla in some arbitrary mixed state $\sigma$? That is, given  a state $\sigma$ of $\mathcal{A}$, I would like to know whether
for every CPTP channel $\Lambda$,
there exists a unitary $U$ on $\mathcal{H}\otimes\mathcal{A}$ such that
$$\Lambda[\rho]=tr_\mathcal{A}(U^\dagger (\rho\otimes \sigma)U).$$